# SFML player movement

Tags: sfml

I have a problem with implementing player movement using SFML on macos.
Player movement works when i use this piece of code:

```
keyRight = event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right;
    keyLeft = event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left;
    keyUp = event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up;
    keyDown = event.type == Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down;
```

but it won't work if I use this:

```
keyRight= sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right);
    keyLeft= sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left);
    keyUp= sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up);
    keyDown= sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down);
```

I wanna use the second method because the first one seems to not work with diagonal movement (it just cant register two keys pressed at once.) Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Could you explain what error is occurring (if there is build errors add them)?

Comment: there are no errors. clicking buttons just dont do anything like the code for reading inputs didnt exist :/

Comment: Solved it. If you are curious what was the problem see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every mac user with same issue I’ve managed to resolve mine. Since os catalina you have to re-give your compiler (or project) permissions to monitor inputs.
More of it here: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=26395.0

You can either click it every time you change anything in your build or use event based movement.